# Sobrepor background

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, imagem

No meu site tenho uma animação que é uma pista de comboio e um comboio que percorre esta mesma pista, mas agora queria sobrepor com uma imagem sem fundo, que seriam túneis, e que ficasse posicionada por cima do comboio.

Este é o meu site como está agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta é a imagem sem fundo com os tuneis nas curvas que estava a falar, não sei se vai dar para ver sem clicar em cima...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E queria colocar esta segunda imagem sobre o site para que o comboio quando passar por elas, passe por trás da imagem.

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas vamos lá. Você quer que a imagem com esses *foobar* azuis fique por cima dos trilhos? Se sim, já tentou colocar uma `div` com `position: fixed` ou tentou colocar um `z-index: 99999`? Já parou pra pensar no dimensionamento do projeto em diferentes clientes?

Comment: eu usei uma div mas com o z-index: 11. Vou tentar

Comment: A imagem nem sequer aparece e devia aparedcer

Comment: Blz, mas não adianta vc simplesmente alterar o z-index. Vc deve posicionar a imagem também. Eu até citei o `position: fixed`, mas acredito que vc deve usar o `position: absolute` ou `position: relative`, senão a imagem vai ficar no mesmo lugar na tela ao rolar a página. No caso de `relative`, coloque dentro da div com o *trilho*. Dica: Utilize uma imagem diferente, para o posicionamento. Mas com a mesma dimensão! Essa imagem dificulta o posicionamento.

Comment: ok vou tentar obrigado

Comment: Posta o código fonte que *tentarei* lhe ajudar, caso se faça necessário.

Answer (score 1):

Com uma *técnica básica de sobreposição*, fiz alguns testes e postarei as minhas conclusões/opiniões no final.

Como não tenho o código fonte, criei o seguinte código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
            max-width:100%;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        div.dvMae {
            border: solid 1px red;
            width: 90%;
            min-height: 70%;
            margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
            padding: 50px;
            background: url('img/teste1.png'); /* SOMENTE PARA TESTE / NO CÓDIGO ORIGINAL PODE APAGAR */
            position: relative;
        }
        div.dvFilho {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: url('img/teste2.png'); /* CAMINHO DA IMAGEM COM OS TÚNEIS */
            background-size: 100% auto;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position:50% -2000px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="dvMae">
            Fubá
            <div class="dvFilho">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Com esse código, cheguei a esse posicionamento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Note que adicionei um fundo *marrom* à sua imagem original para melhor visualização no desenvolvimento.

Considerações:

- O código acima é para fins de instrução/orientação. Adapte-o de acordo com sua necessidade;
- A imagem original está com resolução de `8000 x 14450` pixels e só tem elementos à partir do pixel `6214` (na vertical (`y`)). Em um dispositivo com tela *4k*, a resolução é de `3840 × 2160` pixels. O que conclui que  sua imagem está *absurdamente grande*.
- Recrie a imagem com os túneis considerando o tamanho do alvo a ser sobreposto.
- Considere diferentes resoluções, uma vez que sua página poderá ser visitada em dispositivos diferentes. Conhece o *designer responsivo*?

PS: Estava tentando acessar essa pergunta pelo [App Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=pt-br), no meu celular com *S. O. Android* e o App não aguentou processar a imagem, causando seu fechamento instantâneo.